# Add Custom Panels to FlowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I need to create dynamically Panels, which have certain functionalities. For that I use a FloaLayoutPanel to add those Panels and I want to create custom Panels which provides me with those functionalities. Is it possible to add custom Panels to a FlowLayoutPanel?

I created a class and inherit from Panel. I thought it would be no problem, but it seems that FlowLayoutPanel only takes (raw)Panels.

```
public class MyPanel: Panel
{
    int value;
    public MyPanel(int given_value)
    {
        value = given_value;
    }


}
```

To add my Panel to the FlowLayoutPanel:

```
MyPanel panel = new MyPanel(21);
panel.Click += new EventHandler(panel_clicked);

if (this.layoutPanel.InvokeRequired)
{
   this.layoutPanel.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
   {
         this.layoutPanel.Controls.Add(myPanel);
   });
}
else
{
   this.layoutPanel.Controls.Add(myPanel);
}
```

Is there some way I can create a FlowLayoutPanel with custom Panels?

Comment: I added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no problem adding your customized panels to flowlayoutpanel as it accepts anything that inherits from Control (panel inherits from control and your customized panel from panel). just add it to its controls:

```
MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(myPanel);
```

Comment: Mhh, then my problem must be somewhere esle, I am getting the error:Cannot convert from 'namespace...MyPanel' to 'System.Windows.forms.Control'

Comment: try adding a cunstructor without any parameters like:     `public MyPanel(){ } `

Comment: @Dominick just remove the constructor, and add `given_value` as property.

Comment: I did. currently the class only has a empty constuctor and nothing else. But I just see, that if i create the class in the same location where my method is, there is no problem. But if I create a new class file, and use the class out of that class file it trows again the error :S I stay now with the class in the same file as the methode which adds them, but Is this normal?

Comment: well do you have access to the flowlayoutpanel inside the class? i doubt that, because it is a private control in your form. is't it? so it is normal if you don't have access to it outside.